# Trouble locating a checkbox in an iframe with Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium, checkbox, click

I'm trying to locate a checkbox in an iframe in a Javascript based website using Web Driver and python. I've tried locating by ID and XPATH and neither seem to work since I must be looking in the wrong frame. The checkbox is visible on the page to the user and selenium IDE also seems to come up with the same answer as me, but it still results in 'NoSuchElementException: Message: u'The element could not be found'

html for checkbox: input type="checkbox" onclick="CE.CESECUR.onClickFullSecurity()" id="cefullsecure"

selenium code:
    _settings_ssl_locator = (By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='cefullsecure' and onclick='CE.CESECUR.onClickFullSecurity()']")

```
def click_settings_enable_ssl(self):
    self.selenium.find_element(*self._settings_ssl_locator).select()
```

Comment: actually the checkbox is in an iframe and I dont yet know how to handle different frames with selenium.

Comment: OK I solved it pretty simply by adding

self.selenium.switch_to_frame('iframe_name')

Answer (score 0):

I think you you would need to switch to the frame first and then locate the element, do the task/action on the elements present on the frame and switch back to the previous frame.

```
WebElement checkBoxframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("enter frame name here"));
driver.switchTo().frame(checkBoxframe);
//write your selenium code here for checkbox
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```